# does linq-to-sql handle dynamic queries?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm building a dynamic query. Basically, a function receives an object MyParams whose properties are the parameters; I'm creating the Where clauses based on the MyParams object and returning a list of anonymous type.

So, does L2SQL support creating a dynamic query? I have a data context that already works for other queries. Depending on the parameters, I need to access some tables sometimes so do I also need to write the From clauses dynamically or should I just include all the tables and focus only on the where clauses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this if this is what you want to:

```
        var baseQuery = dataAccess.Table1.Where(arg => arg.Field1 = 1);

        if (parameter[1] = true)
        {
            baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(arg => arg.Field2 = 'Test');
        }

        if (parameter[2] = true)
        {
            baseQuery = 
                from x in baseQuery
                join y in dataAccess.Table2 on
                    x.Id equals y.Id
                where y.Field3 = 'Something'
                select x;
        }

        return baseQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: If I have using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC()), how does this work? What do I do with the multiple from clauses?

Comment: @frenchie don't dispose `MyDC` until you materialized the query. In other words `return baseQuery.ToList()` should be inside of your `using` statement.

Comment: @frenchie: if the return statement is inside the using statement, when the method return the DC is not disposed because it has gone out of scope. If you want to dispose of the DC, you need to assign the value of the `ToList` call to some variable outside the scope of the using (but in the scope of the method), and return that.

Comment: @Matt - not sure I understood you correctly. Are you saying that if you have code like this `using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC()){ return x; }` then TheDC will not be disposed?

Comment: What do you mean by "TheDC will not be disposed"?

Comment: I was just trying to understand Matt's comment. I think he is saying that DC will not be disposed if return is inside of the `using`. If I understood it correctly, then he is wrong.

Comment: @alex sorry, you are right. I forgot that the return is exported out of the try-finaly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450983/linq2sql-or-and-operators-anded-ored-conditions/1451667#1451667) to another question. Your question is not an exact copy yours is more generic but the why to solve the problem is exactly the same.