# dynamic where clause with array

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have an object with a list of int as one of the properties:

```
public class MyObject
{
  public List<int> TheList
}
```

A function receives this object as a parameter for a Linq-To-SQL query and I have this:

```
public static List<MyModel> ConditionalQuery(MyObject TheObject)
{   
  using (MyDataContext TheDC = new MyDataContext())
  {
     var TheListBuilder = (from l in TheDC

                           where l.Property = the elements in the list

                           select l.ID).ToList();

      return new List<MyModel>(TheListBuilder);

  }
}
```

Basically, the parameter contains a list of ints and I need to match these ints with the l.Property. How do you write this type of condition?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where list.Contains(l.Property)
```

for multiple conditions you can do:

```
        var result = (
            from l in TheDC.Table
            where list1.Contains(l.Property1)
            where list2.Contains(l.Property2)
            select l.Id
            ).ToList();
```

or

```
        var result = (
            from l in TheDC.Table
            where list1.Contains(l.Property1) && list2.Contains(l.Property2)
            select l.Id
            ).ToList();
```

Comment: ok, what if I have multiple where clauses like this? What do I do with the query: where do I put the .ToList()

Comment: @frenchie - updated the answer. ToList() should always be in the end as this triggers a request to DB.

Comment: ok, I'm trying this to see what I get. Some of the Properties are only triggered based on the properties of MyObject. How would I write this so that if (TheObject.Property1 == 2) { activate filter }. It looks like I need to build the query in multiple steps.

Comment: @frenchie - Yes, you need to build the query in multiple steps as I showed in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923249/does-linq-to-sql-handle-dynamic-queries/5923278#5923278